# 実機でアプリがビルド出来ません！！

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

本当に誰か助けてください。もう三日くらい戦っています。

以前実機でアプリがビルド出来ていたのに出来なくなってしまいました。

現在Swiftでアプリ開発を行っており、Udemyで学習しているのですが、昨日完成したアプリをビルドしようとしたところ、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画面が出てきました。そこで、ログインパスワードを入力して、「許可」のボタンを押しても反応しなかったため、ネットで検索してみたところ、以下のページを見つけました。

http://www.weblog-life.net/entry/xcode_debug_error

この手順の通りにやったらビルド出来た。という声が多かったので、私もやってみたところ、一応実機でビルドするところまではできるようなりました。これで解決か、、と思ったのですが、実機でアプリを動かそうとすると、Xcodeに以下のエラーメッセージが出てアプリが開けません。

Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Developer: (メールアドレス) ()"

困り果てて、「まさか違うプロジェクトも開けなくなっているのではないか」と思い、違うプロジェクトを実機でビルドしようと試みたところ、以前は実機で動いていたアプリに対しても、上記のエラーコードが出て動かなくなってしまいました。

これは一体どういうことなのでしょうか？初心者の私には全く意味が分からず困っている状況です。
どなたか解決策がわかる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。何卒よろしくお願いします。

ちなみに、

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86161

に書いてある情報を試してもまるでダメでした。何か少しでも手がかりが欲しいです。。

補足情報
MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2015)
macOS 10.13.4
Xcode9.3

Comment: ビルドというとデバッグビルドですかね？とりあえず、１．以前とはドレくらい前のことでしょうか？証明書が切れたり、OSのサポートが切り替わったりする前のことでしょうか？２．`capabilities`で有効にしている項目はありますか？そちらで証明書を必要としていませんか？もし必要な証明書があれば作り直すことをお勧めします。３．参考サイトの再ログイン後アカウント選択時に右側下部に出る`Download Manual Profiles`ボタンでプロファイルの再ダウンロードしても変わりはありませんでしょうか？４．ビルドしようとしているアプリが端末に既にインストールされていたりしませんか？５．`Build Settings`の`Signing`の設定はどうなっておりますか？`Code Signing Style`は`Automatic`ですか？

Comment: あともう一点、開発グループなどで複数人で開発していたり、MemberCenterから直接プロビジョニングファイルなどに変更を加えたりはしていますか？

Comment: Myakuさん
ご回答ありがとうございます！
一つづつ以下回答です。
1,いえ、つい一週間ほど前のことです。
2.Capabilitiesを確認しましたが、全て無効にしてあります。
3.参考サイトの通りDownload Manualのボタンを押しても全く同じエラーが出てしまうので、変化なしです。
4.ビルドしようとしているアプリは端末にダウンロードされていません。
5.Build Setting の Signing を確認しましたが、Code Signing StyleはAutomaticになっていました。

開発は一人で行っており、そのようなことはしていないと思います。
プロビジョニングファイルとはなんなのでしょうか？他のサイトでも調べた際に出てきましたが、いまいち意味が分かりません。

Comment: プロビジョニングファイルとはビルドする際にデバッグビルドならどの端末にインストールするかなどの情報が入ったビルドに必要なファイルになります。
ローカルにキャッシュしているプロビジョニングファイルを削除してからリンク先の手順をもう一度行って変化はありますか？
キャッシュしている先のフォルダの中身を空にすれば新しいものをAppleから取得するはずです。「`~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`」

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/126378

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13190444613

Comment: Myakuさん
コメントありがとうございます。教えてくださった通りにプロヴィジョニングファイルを全て消してから、リンク先の手順を行っても効果がありませんでした。悲しいです。